# Tryinig to parse mutiple files in python using glob but I am confused on how to implement it

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, glob

So I am very new to python so i tend to feel lost at times, I am working on a data science project where I need to parse different files to make different graphs, up until now I have read about glob function but I am not sure how to implement it, I would really appreciate the help.
My file name goes something like this : PRA-DIA_8.1_A_1.stat0, PRA-DIA_8.1_A_1.stat1, PRA-DIA_8.1_A_1.stat3....

I have no issues with parsing a single file but when i want to try it for multiple files then i get lost. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find all files starting with PRA-DIA_8.1_A_1.sta, assuming you're already located within their directory, you can use the following (see the star operator, meaning basically "anything"):

```
import glob
file_paths = glob.glob("./PRA-DIA_8.1_A_1.sta*")
```

Now that you have all filenames, you can parse each one of them:

```
for file_path in file_paths:
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        file_content = f.read()
        ...  # do your supplementary parsing here
```

Comment: do i need to use this in a for loop?

Comment: No, glob's output is a list of all the filenames that match the input path. Here, it would, if  you are in the correct directory, retrieve all filenames that start with this pattern.

Comment: yeah it works, but how to i parse these files now? I can only see the names of these files in the output. My main aim is to parse these files to create a dictionary and then create a graph from this dictionary. Thank u so much for helping out, I had lost all hope of figuring it out and then u helped.

Comment: Oh, then this is a different question. You asked for `glob` which is a useful way to explore your directories and hence retrieve filenames following a given pattern. If you need to parse files, then there are at least as many solutions as there are file extensions. You mention you have no issue parsing a single file: how do you do it? Why can't you do it for all if you can do it for one, now that you have all filenames?

Comment: I am using with open(file path, 'r') as fp: for the single file, i am mentioning the specific file location for it to open.. So are u saying that i can pass the variable containing the list of all the extensions? would that work?

Comment: The parsing logic you use for one file (i.e. `open()` etc.), just do it for all the files using a `for` loop. Edited my answer. If you're not at ease with how to parse a `.sta*` file, please ask this in a new question and accept this one if you're satisfied.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your first comment, you were right suggesting a `for` loop, I thought you were asking for the `glob` part.